# extract property from json with some condition

Tags: c#, .net-core

I want to deserialize the json text.

so i have created a custom model class where i am defining each json property like shown below :

```
[JsonProperty("Grills Exit Date - All ABC")]
        public Dictionary<string, string> prop1 { get; set; }
```

The above code is working fine and i am able to retrieve the text by using the below code.

```
var rawContent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dto>(json);
```

My issue is that one of the json property is like ABC1, ABC2, ABC3 so i want to retrieve the value of all those property that start with ABC

```
    {
    "ABC I": "WP XII",
    "ABC II": "WPFS",
    "ABC III": "No Data Available",
    "Grills Exit Date - All ABC": {
        "WP XII": "6/30/2024 12:00:00 AM",
        "WPFS": "6/30/2024 12:00:00 AM",
        "Combined": "6/30/2024 12:00:00 AM",
        "WP Co-Investor": "No Data Available"
    }
}
```

can someone guide me how do i achieve this

Error :

```
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '['Grills Exit Date - All ABC']', line 4, position 48.'
```

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>().Where(e => e.Key.StartsWith("ABC"))`. The `JsonPropertyAttribute` is for renaming properties.

Comment: @AluanHaddad is it possible to define this in the custom model class as json property and get its value?

Comment: Sure. I don't know if what you've shown is the entire object. You can always create a `get` only property or you can write an extension method.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I want to the way i have done for other property [JsonProperty("myprop")]
        public Dictionary<string, string> prop1 { get; set; }
but unable to achieve this as i am not sure how to mention that starts with

Comment: I don't understand. `[JsonProperty]` is _only_ for renaming. It simply does  not apply here. Maybe you can add an example where you actually use it. You do not need `[JsonProperty]`! It works without that.

Comment: @AluanHaddad i tried this code but it doesnot give me value that starts with ABC it throws error JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json).Where(e => e.Key.StartsWith("ABC"))

Comment: Can you add the complete Dto class along with the json? This is partial and not reproducible

Comment: @Jawad I have added

Comment: @AluanHaddad i have added the error that i am getting

Comment: @Jawad i have added the error that i am getting

Comment: That is not valid JSON.

Comment: @AluanHaddad it is valid

Comment: It is still invalid. Some serializers will try to work with single quotes, but do not count on that. It does not comply with the JSON spec.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Sorry it is in double quotes it was a typo . I have made changes but still it does not work.

Comment: It works fine: `var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dto>(json);
 o.prop1.Where(e => e.Key.StartsWith("WP"));`

Answer (score 0):

Considering your json is like below,

```
{
  "ABC I": "WP XII",
  "ABC II": "WPFS",
  "ABC III": "No Data Available",
  "Grills Exit Date - All ABC": {
    "WP XII": "6/30/2024 12:00:00 AM",
    "WPFS": "6/30/2024 12:00:00 AM",
    "Combined": "6/30/2024 12:00:00 AM",
    "WP Co-Investor": "No Data Available"
  }
}
```

your DTO class should look like this,

```
public class Rootobject
{
    [JsonProperty("ABC I")]
    public string ABCI { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ABC II")]
    public string ABCII { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ABC III")]
    public string ABCIII { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Grills Exit Date - All ABC")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> GrillsExitDateAllABC { get; set; }
}
```

You can use the following code to deserialize the json and then look up the values of all the properties that starts with ABC.

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
foreach (var prop in typeof(Rootobject).GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("ABC")))
    Console.WriteLine(obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(obj, null));

// Prints
WP XII
WPFS
No Data Available
```

What you are basically doing is retrieving all the properties of the class (`DTO`) that has the names starting with `ABC`. Once you have a list of those properties, you can loop through them and get the values for each of those properties from the object based on this class.